# Firefox hex color rendering

Tags: css, firefox

I have a column set up on this page: http://www.aerlawgroup.com/dui.html  (about half way down).

The column divider renders light grey in CHROME and Safari, but it renders BLACK in Firefox.  How can I fix it?  The most annoying part is that I got this code from: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp - So I figured it would work perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
.newspaper
{
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:2;

-moz-column-gap:40px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-gap:40px; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-gap:40px;

-moz-column-rule:1px outset #C6C6C6; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-rule:1px outset #c6c6c6; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-rule:1px outset #c6c6c6;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.5em;
color: #000000;
font-family: "museo-sans", sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}
```

Comment: **Never** assume code from W3Schools will work perfectly... http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Agreed.  But issues with hex values?  Firefox sucks.

Comment: I tried changing -moz-column-rule:1px outset #C6C6C6; to -moz-column-rule:1px solid #C6C6C6; and that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `-moz-column-rule:1px solid #C6C6C6` instead of `-moz-column-rule:1px outset #C6C6C6`
this will work